# Passing path parameter to a React context provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a React context that provides "project" information to child components, and I'd like the keep all things related to project data contained within the context class. An example of this is the "refreshProject" function that retrieves project information from the server. The challenge is: how to pass the projectID, which is a URL param, into the context class? In the code below, I currently pass it into the refresh function itself, which means that all child components that want to call refreshProject need to pull the ID from the URL, which is clumsy. I can think of several approaches to this but I'm curious what would be considered best-practice here.

This is the wrapped route with the project ID contained within the URL:

```
<Switch>
    [other routes here]

    <ProjectContextProvider>
        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/project/:id" exact component={Project} props={childProps} />
    </ProjectContextProvider>
</Switch>
```

And the ProjectContextProvider class looks like:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
import { API } from '../Services'

export const ProjectContext = createContext();

export class ProjectContextProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            project: null,
            refreshProject: this.refresh
        }
    }

// This is what I have
    refresh(projectID) {
        API.getProject(projectID).then(project => {
            this.setState({ project });
        });
    }

// This is what I want
//    refresh() {
//        API.getProject(this.projectID).then(project => {
//            this.setState({ project });
//        });
//    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ProjectContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ProjectContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The challenge is: **how to pass the projectID**, which is a URL param, into the context class?

Of course **by context**:

```
    this.state = {
        projectID: null,
        project: null,
        refreshProject: this.refresh
    }
```

> all child components that want to call refreshProject need to pull the ID **from the URL**

**not true**, it can be read from router (props location etc.)

Make context provider outer to router (routes should be a switch direct children)

```
<ProjectContextProvider>
  <Switch>
    [other routes here]
    <AuthenticatedRoute path="/project/:id" exact component={Project} props={childProps} />
  </Switch>
</ProjectContextProvider>
```

Pass state directly to provider, without spreading (it creates a new object, we want to pass a ref)

```
<ProjectContext.Provider value={this.state}>
  {this.props.children}
</ProjectContext.Provider>
```

In `<Project/>` just mutate directly (usually not advised) `projectID` in context (not using `setState`, change not propagated, dependants not rerendered) `this.context.projectID = someID;` (id from router props), then call `this.context.refreshProject()` - it's binded then it can use `this.state.projectID` to make API request. When done updated context (with setState) will force rerenderings (of context connected components).